# How to group same item into array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

My data is like below

```
[1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,2]
```

How can I turn this array to like

```
[[1,1,1], [2,2], [1,1,1], [2,2], [1,1,1,1,], [2], [1], [2,2]]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using `reduce` method and check if the previous element `i - 1` is equal or not to the current element.

```js
const data = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2]
const result = data.reduce((r, e, i, a) => {
  let last = r[r.length - 1]
  if (!last || e !== a[i - 1]) r.push([e])
  else last.push(e)
  return r
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

This oughta do the trick. I added an option to choose a custom comparator function, but the default is strict equality.

(And before someone says I should use `.forEach()`, this is using a plain old `for...` loop for performance reasons.)

```
function groupSubsequent(input, comparator = (a, b) => a === b) {
  const output = [];
  let currentGroup = null;
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    const item = input[i];
    if (currentGroup === null || !comparator(currentGroup[currentGroup.length - 1], item)) {
      currentGroup = [];
      output.push(currentGroup);
    }
    currentGroup.push(item);
  }
  return output;
}

console.log(groupSubsequent([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2]));
```

Output:

```
[
  [ 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 2, 2 ],
  [ 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 2, 2 ],
  [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 2 ],
  [ 1 ],
  [ 2, 2 ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple reduce and push a new array to the accumulator if the current element doesn't match the last element.

```js
const data = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2];
const res = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const last = acc[acc.length - 1] || []
  if (cur !== last[last.length - 1]) {
    acc.push([cur])
  } else {
    acc[acc.length - 1].push(cur)
  }
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with array reduce:

```js
const arr = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2];

const result = arr.reduce((carrier, item) => {
    const lastArrayInCarrier = carrier[carrier.length - 1]; // Get last sub array

    if (lastArrayInCarrier instanceof Array && lastArrayInCarrier[0] === item) { // If last sub array contains the same numbers as the current iteration, append it
        lastArrayInCarrier.push(item);
    } else { // Else create new sub array with the new number
        carrier.push([item])
    }


    return carrier;
}, []);


console.log(result);
```

output:

```js
[
  [ 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 2, 2 ],
  [ 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 2, 2 ],
  [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 2 ],
  [ 1 ],
  [ 2, 2 ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
        var x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2];
        
        var arr = []
        var temp = []
        for (i = 0; i<x.length;i++) {
            if (x[i] == x[i + 1]) {
                arr.push(x[i]);
            }else{
                arr.push(x[i]);
                temp.push(arr);
                arr = []
            }
        }
        console.log(temp);
```